# Only first item of each json data in listview with different layout android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am working on custom `listview` which has `StoreName` as header and `items of its store` as child

My json data :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "response": [
        {
            "store_id": "1",
            "store_name": "Prashant Stores",
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "1",
                    "item_name": "Kellogs Cornflakes",
                    "item_price": "75",
                    "item_size": "500 mg",
                    "item_quantity": "1",
                    "item_total": "75",
                    "delivery_boy_status_id": "3",
                    "delivery_boy_status": "Delivered",
                    "is_available": "1"
                },
                {
                    "item_id": "2",
                    "item_name": "Chocos",
                    "item_price": "75",
                    "item_size": "1 kg",
                    "item_quantity": "1",
                    "item_total": "75",
                    "delivery_boy_status_id": "3",
                    "delivery_boy_status": "Delivered",
                    "is_available": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "store_id": "5",
            "store_name": "Corner Stores",
            "items": [
                {
                    "item_id": "4",
                    "item_name": "Chocos",
                    "item_price": "400",
                    "item_size": "1 kg",
                    "item_quantity": "1",
                    "item_total": "400",
                    "delivery_boy_status_id": "1",
                    "delivery_boy_status": "To be Collected",
                    "is_available": "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": ""
}
```

I wanted a `listview` to be like this

[image]

my adapter

```
public class CustomerwiseDeatilsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


    UtilClass utilClass;
    private Activity context;
    private List<CustomerwiseDetailsModel> list;
    private String TAG = "OrderHistoryAdapter";
    int isHeaderAdded = 0;
    List<String> storeList;

    public CustomerwiseDeatilsAdapter(Activity context, List<CustomerwiseDetailsModel> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        storeList = new ArrayList<>();
        utilClass = new UtilClass();
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return list.size();
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        /*if (position == 0) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }*/
        return position%2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        final CustomerwiseDetailsModel model = list.get(position);


        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            ViewHolderHeader viewHolderHeader;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolderHeader = new ViewHolderHeader();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_neworders_customer_wise_details, parent, false);
                viewHolderHeader.txt_store_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.storename);
                //for each field of holder find the subview
                convertView.setTag(viewHolderHeader);
            } else {
                viewHolderHeader = (ViewHolderHeader) convertView.getTag();
            }
            //set the data in subview with holder fields
            viewHolderHeader.txt_store_name.setText(model.getStore_name());
        } else {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.neworders_customer_wise_details_linearlayout, null, false);

                viewHolder.txt_item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_name);
                viewHolder.txt_item_size = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_product_weight);
                viewHolder.txt_item_quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_recurring_total_price_qnty);
                viewHolder.txt_item_total = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_recurring_total_price);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.txt_item_name.setText(model.getItem_name());
            viewHolder.txt_item_size.setText(model.getItem_size());
            viewHolder.txt_item_quantity.setText(model.getItem_price() + " x" + model.getItem_quantity());
            viewHolder.txt_item_total.setText(model.getItem_total());
        }





        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_item_name;
        TextView txt_item_size;
        TextView txt_item_quantity;
        TextView txt_item_total;
    }

    class ViewHolderHeader {
        TextView txt_store_name;
    }
}
```

my output :
[image]

Comment: ExpandableListView is what you need.

Comment: no ... a normal listview ...

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: And what if the recycled view is not the view you expect for that type?

Comment: Check this link http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/

Comment: You are recycling Views which are not the same...this won't work unless you do some manipulation on the view.

Comment: you can use expandable listview as suggested by @DhavalPatel or use the method mentioned in the answer below..

Answer (score 1):

One idea. Use the same layout for all cells. And in the cell layout add the header of the category. Then on getView decide if you want to show the header or hide it with Visibility.GONE. To decide this you can see the current and the next element in the array to check if categories are different (show) or the same (hide)

Comment: let me first try this :)

Comment: Sure, if you have some problems just ask